ConcurrentQueue with many enqueuers and single dequeuer
I'm using a ConcurrentQueue<T>. I need:

multiple consumers to enqueue items
a single consumer to dequeue all items in one go
during the dequeue, to lock the queue so other consumers cannot enqueue new items at the same time

public class Cache
{

  private readonly ConcurrentQueue<Item> _queue = new();

  public void Enqueue(Item item)    // what synchronisation to perform here?
  {
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(item, nameof(item));
    _queue.Enqueue(item);
  }

  public void Flush()               // what synchronisation to perform here?
  {
    // dequeue all items
    var items = new List<Item>();
    while (_queue.TryDequeue(out var item))
      items.Add(item);

    // `DoSomething` could take time; therefore above we
    // dequeued and cached all items, so other consumers
    // can immediately continue enqueuing
    foreach (var item in items)
      DoSomething(item);
  }

  public void DoSomething(Item item)
  {
    // ...
  }

}

I'm confused which is the best concurrency tool to synchronise access to _queue (in Enqueue and Flush).
Should I use a simple lock, or something more exotic?
UPDATE: to address the comments below, I'm not attached to ConcurrentQueue; if there's a more appropriate concurrent collection, please tell me.

"during the dequeue, lock the queue so other consumers cannot enqueue new items at the same time." -- It might be useful for future viewers to explain the rational behind this requirement.

The simplest option would be to just use a lock and a list:
public class Cache
{
    private List<Item> _queue = new();
    private readonly Lock _lockObj = new();
    public void Enqueue(Item item)
    {
        lock (_lockObj)
        {
            _queue.Add(item);
        }
    }

    public void Flush()
    {
        List<Item> items;
        lock (_lockObj)
        {
            items = _queue;
            _queue = new List<Item>();
        }
        foreach (var item in items)
            DoSomething(item);
    }

    public void DoSomething(Item item)
    {
        ...
    }
}

This should perform fairly well given that the lock is only held momentarily. You might want to set the list capacity to avoid somewhat expensive reallocations. There are almost certainly other faster way to do this, but optimizations usually have a cost in readability.
But the question reveals a possible problematic view. The only point where the queue is guaranteed to be empty is just after _queue = new List<Item>(), before the lock is released. But you are not doing anything at this point, and as soon as the lock is released there might be items in the queue again.
Put in another way, a thread that enqueues an item has no way to know if it was included in a flush or not, not unless there is some other form of synchronization. Nor can the flushing thread know if there is pending enqueues. So there should not really be any difference compared to your original version.
So it is not really clear what the actual goal is. Statements like "a single point in time" are problematic since there is no global ordering. The only order you can rely on is the one provided by the various synchronization primitives. Is DoSomething required to be synchronized with regards to Enqueue? If so it needs to be run inside the lock. Maybe you need some external synchronization to ensure all enqueuing has been done before flushing?
In general I would suggest taking a look at BlockingCollection, I find that more useful than raw ConcurrentQueues. DataFlow and Channels might be other libraries to consider.

Mind for dotnet 9+ => ... _lockObj = new Lock(); => Lock Class

While your code is safe, it is doing a mistake no decent concurrent container should do which is to allocate under a lock, allocations can take up to 100 microseconds to complete, you should keep the old list around and reuse it to reduce allocations. (Add will reallocate less, and no pesky new under the lock)

Thank you. Your solution works for me. And I'll take a look at BlocingCollection too as your recommended.

@AhmedAEK your criteria of decency are quite arbitrary. The BoundedChannel<T> is implemented with a lock-protected Deque<T>. When the deque is full, the TryWrite allocates under a lock. I consider the BoundedChannel<T> to be a decent concurrent container. Sometimes allocating under a lock is good enough, or even the best you can do.

@JonasH Am I right in assuming that you opted for a List rather than ConcurrentQueue, because if one must lock the Enqueue operation, then the latter's synchronisation capabilities are not used anyway, and so the former is faster and simpler?

@TheodorZoulias BoundedChannel is reusing its memory and only the first few writes make allocations, the above answer would do the same if it reuses the list, and both don't qualify as decent concurrent containers. Lock free ring buffers have a much better performance as a "Bounded channel" and is being used in any realtime critical system.

@lonix Yes, a list should be faster and simpler if it is used within a lock anyway.

@AhmedAEK the Cache in this answer also allocates sporadically, not on every Enqueue. The cost of memory allocation is amortized. Your suggestion of reusing the same list comes with the risk of excessive memory usage for no good reason. If the casual size of the cache is 1,000, but momentarily peaks at 1,000,000, you'll end up with 999,000 empty slots hanging around until the process terminates. If you don't mind wasting your memory like this, you might as well use the existing implementation and just instantiate the List<T> with a humongous initial size that will never need to grow.

@TheodorZoulias pre-allocating a large list is a viable solution, just do it outside the lock.

@AhmedAEK it is viable, but I don't think that it's justified. I wouldn't expect to see measurable performance improvements from a benchmark. The cost of synchronization should dwarf the cost of sporadic allocations.

@TheodorZoulias it will be justified when you are explaining to your product manager why your application has a few hundred of microseconds of no thread making any progress because one thread is taking a lock will allocating memory from the kernel and all the other threads are waiting on it, on an 8+ core machine you are losing milliseconds of work per spike, it depends on how contended this container is.

@AhmedAEK growing small lists should take nanoseconds, not microseconds. .NET is very efficient at allocating memory. If your benchmarks say otherwise, please share them with us. And please keep in mind that growing a List<T> from zero to 1,000,000 elements takes only ~20 allocations. Do you really expect that the cost of twenty allocations is comparable or greater to one million lock acquisitions?

@AhmedAEK While keeping old lists for future reuse might be a bit faster, it would add a fair bit of complexity. And I do not agree with dogmatic statements like "never new under a lock". As with many other things, it depend on the use case.  "Hundreds of microseconds" is probably not a concern for something that takes several seconds. So context is important, and it does not sound like the OPs primary concern is performance.

A simple approach would be to just read the number of items in the queue at the start of the Flush method. Then instead of reading all the items in the queue, you only read how many there were at the start. Since you're doing all the reading on one thread, you don't have to worry about any collisions. And producers can happily keep adding more items.
That said, it's hard to tell with the information you provided, but I doubt even that is necessary. Why not just read all the items? You're concerned that DoSomething is expensive; but just reading the items into a list isn't. Is there really a functional difference between "read count, then read count items, then process them" and "read all items, then process them"? Just separate the parts "reading the items" from "processing the items", and you're essentially at the same point.
If you want to set a harder limit, you'd have to use a reader-writer lock. Publishers take a read lock when pushing, consumer takes a write lock. Write lock waits for all read locks to be released, then no more read locks can be taken until the write lock is released. As soon as you build your "items to process" list, you can release the write lock and the publishers can continue pushing.
But with what you've shown it's hard to see why this would be in any way better than the naïve approach :) Whatever synchronization you need to do, why is there a difference between "the start of Flush method" and "reading all the items into a buffer"? If you rely on that kind of difference, your code isn't really thread-safe anyway, since you have no constraints on how Flush is called; it's perfectly legal for the runtime to cause, say, a 10s wait on entry to the method. If that breaks your mechanism, you need a better mechanism.
